# How do I build a JSON by and traverse it at the same time?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an array called `pathlist`. Our assumption is the array and its child arrays lenght is n approaching infinity.

```
let pathlist = [
  [ 'en', 'family-law' ],
  [ 'en', 'family-law', 'marriage' ],
  [ 'en', 'family-law', 'divorce' ],
  [ 'en', 'family-law', 'religious-divorce' ],
  [ 'en', 'human-rights-law' ],
  [ 'en', 'refugee-law' ] 
  ...
]
```

I want to loop through this list and build a JSON. In this example it would look like this. Is there a method anyone can suggest?

```
navigator = {
   'en': {
       'family-law': {
          'marriage': {},
          'divorce': {},
          'religious-divorce': {}
       },
       'human-rights-law': {},
       'refugee-law': {},
       ...
    }
}
```

And this is my regrettably incoherent answer.

```
let navigator = {}
let stem
for(let path of pathlist){
    for(let pathitem of path){
        stem = navigator
        if(stem[pathitem]){
            stem = stem[pathitem]
        } else {
            stem[pathitem] = {}
        }
        navigator = {...navigator, stem}
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried. SO isn't a free code writing service. The objective here is for you to post your attempts to solve your own issue and others help when they don't work as expected. See [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Let me clean it up. But let me warn you, it's pretty bad.

Comment: That's ok. Showing any effort is better than no effort and also allows people to help steer you rather than just write all new code. You learn more when someone can point out issues in what you tried and explain how to improve it

Comment: @charlietfl Done

Comment: So where does `navigator` come from?

Comment: My bad, i was disecting it from my code base. But Navigator would be the result JSON. It would be initialized as an empty JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close. Here's a working example with only some minor adjustments using your `for` loops.

Note in each iteration of the outer loop `stem` starts as the `navigator` object.

Then each iteration of the inner loop it becomes a branch of that object

```js
let navigator = {}

for(let path of pathlist){
    let stem = navigator;
    for(let pathitem of path){ 
        stem = stem[pathitem] =  stem[pathitem] || {};             
    }   
}

console.log(navigator)
```

```html
<script>

let pathlist = [
  [ 'en', 'family-law' ],
  [ 'en', 'family-law', 'marriage' ],
  [ 'en', 'family-law', 'divorce' ],
  [ 'en', 'family-law', 'religious-divorce' ],
  [ 'en', 'human-rights-law' ],
  [ 'en', 'refugee-law' ] 
 
]

</script>
```

Comment: @PoulKruijt Sure... I was just wanting to help OP see with only minor variations in what they already had

Comment: You were actually right. I didn't notice it was a double assignment, I thought it was an `?:` statement :)

Answer (score 1):

You could simply iterate the keys for building a new nested structure, if required.

```js
const
  setStructure = (target, keys) => (keys.reduce((o, k) => o[k] ??= {}, target), target),
  pathlist = [['en', 'family-law'], ['en', 'family-law', 'marriage'], ['en', 'family-law', 'divorce'], ['en', 'family-law', 'religious-divorce'], ['en', 'human-rights-law'], ['en', 'refugee-law']],
  result = pathlist.reduce(setStructure, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Didn't know this operator yet `??=`, so that's one to remember. However the original question mentions a nested array of arrays. Perhaps you can expand your answer to take this into consideration

Comment: For some reason the `??=` operator does not work on Node.

Comment: you could replace `o[k] ??= {}` with `o[k] = o[k] || {}`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest would be to use a reduce:

```
let pathlist = [
  [ 'en', 'family-law' ],
  [ 'en', 'family-law', 'marriage' ],
  [ 'en', 'family-law', 'divorce' ],
  [ 'en', 'family-law', 'religious-divorce' ],
  [ 'en', 'human-rights-law' ],
  [ 'en', 'refugee-law' ] 
  ...
];

const json = pathlist.reduce((joined, item) => {
  // set target to result list so far
  let target = joined;

  // loop entries of current item
  // set target to new entry or empty object if it doesn't exist
  item.forEach((entry) => target = target[entry] ??= {});

  // return results until done
  return joined;
}, {});
```